# XSS Within Javascript Data

Tags: javascript, xss

While working on a webapp, I discovered that upon bootstrapping your application, dangerous characters can actually exist within the initial data:

```
<body>
    <script>
        var users = [
            { id: 1, bio: 'My beautiful bio' },
            { id: 2, bio: '</script><script>alert("hello")</script>' }
        ]
    </script>
</body>
```

This was news to me, as I always thought that since the XSS attack exists within the JavaScript, it would be recognized as just a string and would not be dangerous until you actually go to render it within the DOM, but sure enough, that code above is an effective attack.

If I'm understanding correctly, to bootstrap an app with some starter data then, you should translate all/any characters into their respected HTML entities on the server-side, then translate them back into their original characters in order to prevent double escaping upon rendering into the DOM? Why doesn't the parser just treat it as a string since it's wrapped in quotes and exists within a script?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hgk7eux/

Comment: That's not JSON, it's JavaScript.

Comment: take a look at this.http://benalpert.com/2012/08/03/preventing-xss-json.html

Comment: The HTML parser runs first, and parses out the HTML. Which means it sees the first </script> and thinks the javascript block stops there.

Comment: Also here is a blog post about this type of XSS I wrote back in 2009: http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=91

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've posted is two `<script>` blocks. The first one will fail with a syntax error, and the second one will run the `alert()`. Here's the first script:

```
<script>
    var users = [
        { id: 1, bio: 'My beautiful bio' },
        { id: 2, bio: '</script>
```

And here's the second one:

```
<script>alert("hello")</script>
```

The appearance of the string `</script>` ends a script block regardless of the JavaScript context it appears in.

As to your broader question, yes, you have to sanitize user-supplied text when including it in a JavaScript context. The simplest way to do that is to use a JSON encoder. JSON encoders generally include `/` in the list of characters that must be quoted with `\` inside JavaScript string constants. That feature would have protected you because `</script>` would be rendered as `<\/script>`.

Any JSON expression is a valid JavaScript object initializer string (or, if a JSON encoder is asked to encode a primitive string, a valid string constant).

Finally, always applying HTML encoding is definitely **not** what you should do if you want your application to work properly. The type of sanitization that must be applied to user-supplied text depends on the syntax of the parser to which it's being fed. You apply different sanitization for SQL, for server-side log files, for HTML, and for JavaScript.

Comment: What would the sanitized data look like? I tried changing it to '<\/script>' but I still receive a syntax error, although the attack is prevented. Are JSON encoders generally the kind of thing you use a library for, or should modern server-side frameworks do it by default?

Comment: @ncksllvn Most server-side environments have JSON encoders, though sometimes (for example, in the Java world) not as a "standard" tool but instead via various widely-available add-ons.  If you're still getting a syntax error however it may be due to the missing `}` at the end of that object literal (the one with the fishy string in it).

Comment: @ncksllvn when you include the backslashes in the string constant, that code parses just fine. I just copied and pasted it into my JavaScript console and it works.

Comment: Wow can't believe I missed that `}`. That worked though! Much easier than doing the HTML entities thing. Thanks a ton. At any point when I think I know a lot, I'm reminded I just scratched the surface.